# How to handle mouse over rating pop up in Amazon website in Selenium Webdriver/Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to check/verify the rating of some product in Amazon Website. I have attached a pic for better understanding. This pop up( or this a call out page??)comes when we hover above stars. Once I get pop up ,I want to click/ verify all 3 star ratings by clicking "3 Star" hyperlink in the pop up.

In the below 3 lines of code, I am hovering above rating element then I will get the pop up. Now in the pop up I want to click on "3 star"

```
 Actions action=new Actions(driver);
 WebElement stars=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='result_0']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span/span/a/i[1]/span")
 );
 action.moveToElement(stars).build().perform();
```

Appreciate your help.
[How to handle highlighted area in Selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1eTj.png)

Comment: What is the error you're getting with your code?

Comment: When I did following            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='histogramTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/span[1]/a")).click();  I am getting noSuchElementException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the script used for hovering implement an explicit wait and click on the 3 star hyperlink.

Heres an example:

```
WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath of the 3 star hyperlink")));

element.click();
```

Let me know if this helps.